# How to match multiple strings with Where-Object/Wildcards?

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

I'm asked to extract commands using `Get-Command`, where the verb is one of `get`, `set` or `convertTo` and the noun starts with any of `C`, `X` or `V`.

This is what I have so far:

```
Get-Command | ?{$_ -like "set[-][CXV]*"} #Prints all commands that start with Set
```

I am struggling to search for multiple verbs that are either `set`, `get`, or `ConvertTo`. I have attempted several different methods but to no avail.

Comment: You can continue the expression by chaining the condition with `-and`, or `-or`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started off correctly, however, `-like` lets you match only wildcard patterns whereas `-match` let you match regex patterns and your regex just needs a little tweaking:

```
Get-Command | ?{$_ -match "((^set)|(^get)|(^convertto))-[CXV]+"}
```

This can be further shortened to:

```
Get-Command | ?{$_ -match "((^[sg]et)|(^convertto))-[CXV]+"}
```

If you want a sorted output of the commands:

```
Get-Command | ?{$_ -match "((^[sg]et)|(^convertto))-[CXV]+"} | Sort
```

Ref: [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.0)

Answer (score 3):

here is how i would do it ... using a `Get-Command` built in parameter = `-Verb`.

what the code does ...

- creates the list of verbs to match
- creates a regex char-at-start-of-string list pattern
- grabs the commands that have the desired verbs
- filters for the commands with nouns that start with the desired chars
- sorts the resulting commands by `Verb` then by `Noun`

the code ...

```
$VerbList = @(
    'get'
    'set'
    'convertto'
    )

$Regex_NounStartsWith = '^[cxv]'

Get-Command -Verb $VerbList |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Noun -match $Regex_NounStartsWith
        } |
    Sort-Object -Property Verb, Noun
```

truncated results ...

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                      
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                      
Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Csv                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility                                                                
Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Xml                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility                                                                
Function        Get-CallerPreference                               5.31.0     PSLog                                                                                       
Function        Get-CallerPreference                               5.22.0     PSLog                                                                                       
Cmdlet          Get-Certificate                                    1.0.0.0    PKI                                                                                         
Cmdlet          Get-CertificateAutoEnrollmentPolicy                1.0.0.0    PKI                                                                                         
Cmdlet          Get-CertificateEnrollmentPolicyServer              1.0.0.0    PKI                                                                                         
Cmdlet          Get-CertificateNotificationTask                    1.0.0.0    PKI                                                                                         
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                              
[*...snip...*]
```

Comment: Is this not too complicated?

Comment: @Suraj - _to me_, it is quite simple. _to me_, yours is the more complex. plus, mine uses NO aliases, uses the built in parameters instead of regex where applicable, and is easy to see/read/understand. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

- [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command)'s `-Name` parameter accepts [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), which allow you to directly filter by the first character of the noun part: `-Name *-[CXV]*`
- While you can *not* directly combine `-Name` with the `-Verb` parameter that is shown in [Lee Dailey's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70132458/45375), you can perform post-filtering via the `.Verb` *property* of the [`[System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo) instances that `Get-Command` outputs:

```sh
Get-Command -Name *-[CXV]* | Where-Object Verb -in Get, Set, ConvertTo
```

Another option, with a single `Where-Object` script block that avoids pattern matching altogether (`$_.Noun[0]` returns the noun part's first character):

```sh
Get-Command | 
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Noun[0] -in 'C', 'X', 'V' -and $_.Verb -in 'Get', 'Set', 'ConvertTo'
  }
```

---

Yet another option is to use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), as shown in [Suraj's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134156/45375) - though its added complexity can be avoided with the wildcard / object-oriented solutions above.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$_ -like "set[-][CXV]*"`

***Wildcard expressions* aren't sophisticated enough to match one of a given set of *substrings*** (only a set of *individual characters* can be matched, such `[CXV]` in your attempt).

The solution is to either match just against `*-[CXV]*` to filter the noun part and add an *additional* comparison with `-and` for the verb part (such as `$_.Verb -in 'Get', 'Set', 'ConvertTo'`, as shown above), or to use a *regular expression* instead, as shown in Suraj's answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, the regex path is better . . . but to answer your actual question about wildcards, I'm going to have to share an answer that people are gonna just poop on. I will have to disagree with [mklement0's assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70136502/4104612) that this can't be done with wildcards (aka "-like" matching).

```
$matches="Get*","Set*","ConvertTo*"    # List of substrings to match
Get-Command | ? {foreach ($match in $matches) {if ($_ -ilike $match) {return $true}}}    # The actual matching
```

Note, I used "-ilike" because I decided to be case insensitive.

Here's more on PowerShell comparison operators: > [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3) <

Its not pretty, but you can store it in a list and match what you're looking to match. I'm sure if you were looking through 6 trillion records for 4 million matches, this would be slow . . . but since we're talking about scripting, it gets the job done.